# What are typical values for bone mass in humans?

Tags: human-anatomy

I wonder what are typical bone mass values for adult males and females? And do they change significantly with workout and diet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder what are typical bone mass values for adult males and females?

This seems hard to find. The only value I could find is on Bionumbers at it says that vertebrates compact bones have a mean density of 2 mg/cm$^3$ [1]. However in medical practice two scores are used to indicate the ratio between tested bone density and ideal bone density [2, 3] and absolute values are uncommon.

> And do they change significantly with workout and diet?

Bone mass is mainly influenced by genetic factors. Only up to 25 % may be influenced by environmental factors such as diet and exercise [4].

Among the medical conditions that influence bone mass, osteoporosis is the most frequent especially in women. Other conditions are: hyperparathyroidism, glucocorticoid therapy, other bone abnormalities and fractures [2].

---

References:

1. Brian Cotterell, Fracture and Life, Imperial College Press, 2010 p.77 bottom paragraph via http://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu//bionumber.aspx?id=108642&ver=2
2. Bone density. (2014, September 15). In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 17:08, September 29, 2014, from http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bone_density&oldid=625737182
3. http://www.niams.nih.gov/Health_Info/Bone/Bone_Health/bone_mass_measure.asp
4. http://www.niams.nih.gov/Health_Info/Bone/Osteoporosis/bone_mass.asp

Comment: it is really hard to find absolute values. maybe because it is hard to estimate, or maybe just because total mass is irrelevant for medical interest. my motivation was actually a bit off-topic, I wanted to know if my body composition estimator scale gives reasonable values.